# fiware POI: cannot add poi: always unauthorized

Tags: fiware, point-of-interest, horizon, fiware-poi

I have two instances:

1. keyrock
2. Poi with wilma-proxy

Trying to create a poi in instance, allways the response is 401 Permission denied. But token is correct as said proxy log:

```
2016-10-14 09:40:30.132  - INFO: IDM-Client - Token in cache, checking timestamp...
2016-10-14 09:40:30.135  - INFO: IDM-Client - Token in cache expired
2016-10-14 09:40:30.136  - INFO: IDM-Client - Checking token with IDM...
2016-10-14 09:40:30.342  - INFO: Root - Access-token OK. Redirecting to app...
Refused to set unsafe header "content-length"
2016-10-14 09:40:30.366  - ERROR: HTTP-Client - Error:  401 Permission denied.
```

So, i think the problem is the **authenticate.html** file. The only lines i changed are:

```
<meta name="fiware_lab-signin-client_id"
content="8dc5826cdaea4729a4f43a01d01cb32e">   
<meta name="fiware_lab-signin-host" content="http://myserver.com:8000">
```

fiware_lab-signin-client_id has the client_id of application POI created in my keyrock instance. 
the fiware_lab-signin-host has the server AND port of horizon.

Is that correct? I try with 5000 port (keystone) without results.

Also, I found this in **add_poi.php**:

```
$session = get_session();   
  $user_id = $session['user'];  
  $add_permission = $session['permissions']['add'];  
  if(!$add_permission) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    die("Permission denied.");   
  }
```

If comment these lines, all proccess seems to be correct until the sql insert. (needs the `$session['user']` and other parameters that are null)

I dont understand why these lines are there. also, the function `get_session()` returns a hardcoded array and not the session (which may not have)

I'm so confused how to use this enabler. Anyone knows how to use?

Comment: Could you give a detailed version information of the POI software? E.g. a link to the commit would be helpful.

Comment: get_session() returns a hardcoded array, if login has not been successful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the `auth_conf.json` file with the root user(s) of the POI-DP? [Configuring hard users](http://fiware-poidataprovider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/POI_Data_Provider__Installation_and_Administration_Guide/#configuring_hard_users) The POI-DP considers the Keystone as a general identity provider (as Google+). You have to separately give permissions to the POI-DP users, first configuring the root users **with all privileges** and then they can call other users using user_management.html . [Site Administration](http://fiware-poidataprovider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/POI_Data_Provider__Installation_and_Administration_Guide/#site-administration)

Please, use the tag `fiware-poi` for quicker response to POI-DP questions.

Comment: im confused with this. I check my auth_conf.json and is only a copy of auth_conf.json. I change permissions on **john doe** to trying an example of adding poi, but also says **Permission denied**.

Comment: Please, read the configuration instructions from http://fiware-poidataprovider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/POI_Data_Provider__Installation_and_Administration_Guide/#configuring_hard_users . You have to configure the admin (and other) permissions for your own KeyStone account.